# confused by the UIImageOrientation of portrait/landscape mode photo

Tags: ios, objective-c, landscape-portrait, uiimageorientation

I take two photos using the ios`s system camera,which one is in portrait mode and another is in landscape mode, then I use imagePicker to pick them out in my app like this:

```
-(void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{

    UIImage* sourceImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];


    UIImageOrientation imageOrientation = sourceImage.imageOrientation;
    NSLog(@"%d",imageOrientation);

}
```

Note that I NSLog out the UIImageOrientation value of the image I just picked out.
the result is the value for the **portrait mode photo is 3**(which represents UIImageOrientationRight) and the **landscape mode photo is 0** (UIImageOrientationUp) I just do not understand why. can anyone explain that? thanks!

Comment: Check out this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10850184/ios-image-get-rotated-90-degree-after-saved-as-png-representation-data

Comment: This question brought me to the correct answer.  That aught to account for an up-vote.

Comment: That question was down-voted for no valid reason. It's a perfectly valid question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iPhone's camera save photo regardless to the device orientation but it adds a metainformation to image to allow this image rendered properly. `imageOrientation` describes the amount of degrees the image should be rotated to be properly rendered.

Comment: Thanks @Max K.! so the UIImageOrientationRight for portrait photo means the system has to rotate the image CCW 90 degree to render it properly?

Comment: Yes, please, look at the `UIImage` reference for more information http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html. Read carefully to understand what those constants actually mean.

Comment: it's incredibly confusing/strange that it seems to save as a landscape??  so the always-default portrait mode is UIImageOrientationRight. I think.