# IOS Take Picture with Custom Camera View

Tags: iphone, ios, camera, xcode4.5, avfoundation

I'm currently developing my first iPhone application. I've implemented a custom camera view where the camera view is displayed through my regular view in a rectangle set by a frame:

```
    AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *captureVideoPreviewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:session];
[captureVideoPreviewLayer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];

[captureVideoPreviewLayer setFrame:CGRectMake(viewLayer.frame.origin.x, viewLayer.frame.origin.y, viewLayer.bounds.size.width, viewLayer.bounds.size.height)];
```

This works good but when I try to take a picture and cutting it with the same rectangle the image rotates 90 degrees. I can't figure out why it does this.

Is there any way I could detect what my "camera window" sees and then crop my taken picture with the same window?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10850184/ios-image-get-rotated-90-degree-after-saved-as-png-representation-data

Answer (score 0):

The image has the native orientation of the camera sensor, which records images the same way no matter how you're holding the device. You can look at the `imageOrientation` property of a UIImage to figure out how to display the image.