# Pics are sideways on iOS (using HTML Input)

Tags: html, ios, firebase, webview, wkwebview

I have this HTML code to allow a user to upload a picture on my hybrid iOS app:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*">
```

When selected, the web view gives the user 2 options. 
1. Take a new picture 2. Choose an existing picture.

When the users selects 'Choose an existing picture' everything works fine. But if the user selects 'Take a new picture', when it uploads to [Firebase Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/), it somehow uploads sideways.

How can I fix this? This is not ideal, but is there a way to only allow an 'existing picture' option?

Here is my code that processes the image and shows it in a `<img>`.

```
function fileUploaded(files) {

  var file = files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();

  reader.onload = function (e) {

    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = e.target.result;

    img.onload = function () {

      var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");

      var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
      canvas.width = 200;
      canvas.height = 200;
      var xStart = 0;
      var yStart = 0;
      var newHeight = 0;
      var newWidth = 0;
      var aspectRadio = img.height / img.width;

      if (img.height < img.width) {
        //horizontal
        aspectRadio = img.width / img.height;
        newHeight = 200;
        newWidth = aspectRadio * 200;
        xStart = -(newWidth - 200) / 2;
      } else {
        //vertical
        newWidth = 200;
        newHeight = aspectRadio * 200;
        yStart = -(newHeight - 200) / 2;
      }


      var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      ctx.drawImage(img, xStart, yStart, newWidth, newHeight);

      dataurl = canvas.toDataURL(file.type);
      document.getElementById('img_element').src = dataurl;


    }

  }
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);

}
```

Comment: Is the sideways upload consistent? If so, you could always reorient the image before upload. I realize that this is not an ideal solution, but if nothing else works then maybe this might.

Comment: Sometimes its upside down and sometimes sideways. I guess there is no way to know.

Answer (score -1):

Are you displaying the image before uploading? You might want to do that to see if it is already rotated by iOS (similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10850184/ios-image-get-rotated-90-degree-after-saved-as-png-representation-data)). As for a fix, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20600800/js-client-side-exif-orientation-rotate-and-mirror-jpeg-images) might be what you will want to use.

Edit:
My previous response was somewhat vague. To be more precise, you're having a problem with the EXIF orientation. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/z13p25vw/) is a JSFiddle that will show you the orientation of the image and how it looks as an `<img/>` vs. as a `<canvas>`. The fix previously mentioned is still the path you will probably want to take. You should be able to use the library to correctly orient the image in a `<canvas>`. [Here](http://blueimp.github.io/JavaScript-Load-Image/) is an example of that library in use. Hope this helps!